# MKS/ PTC Integrity Source equivalent to svn:ignore

Tags: version-control, mks, mks-integrity

We use MKS/PTC Integrity for source control at my work.  Is there an equivalent to the svn:ignore flag from subversion?

Essentially, I'd like a way to tell MKS to ignore a folder / file for changes.  (Ie., our compiler output folders, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set global ignore filters by opening the following menu:

`File->Edit Preferences...`

and then selecting:

`Configuration Management->Views->Non-Members View`

---

An alternative is to select:

`Sandbox->Views->View Non-Members`

and then right-click a file and `Exclude by [Name|Extension]`

Answer (score 1):

This is only filtering the Non-members View.
See http://communities.ptc.com/message/227385#227385 for another answer.
In short have a look to the Scoped Sandbox feature.

Comment: This works much better, though it has to be noted that if there are deferred/pending operations in the folder that's declared "out of scope", the folder won't be filtered out of the view until after those operations have been dealt with.