# MKS cleaning projects of not useful files

Tags: mks, mks-integrity

I am using MKS on mi work daily, and I work with a very big repository thata contains a lot of projects, with a very colorful structure. On my department, we want to improve this project erasing all the optional files (.suo, .pdb, .txt, bin folders, obj folders, and more).
I know, that I can configure the files/folders that I want that the MKS ignore

it is explained here([MKS/ PTC Integrity Source equivalent to svn:ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377774/mks-equvilant-to-svnignore))
 but, 
is there any way to make a selective erase of all these kind of files without having to check out all the files, deleting all the files I want to, and check in again these changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a scoped sandbox with specified filter. See http://communities.ptc.com/message/227385#227385.

Answer (score 1):

(Disclosure:  I am a PTC employee who works in Integrity Support)

To erase those files, you should just drop them.  It is possible that you do not have drop permissions, in which case you will either need to get someone who does have those permissions to perform the drop, or have the permission to do so added to your permission set.

Assuming you have permission, you can select the members you wish to drop, and perform one of the following gestures:

1. From the menu: **Member->Drop**
2. From the context menu: **Drop Members**
3. From the keyboard:  [Delete]

The members will still exist in the archive, but will no longer be visible in your repository.